# how do I manage specific versions of builds with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The generally accepted practice is to have a file named `Dockerfile` in a clean directory where anything I might need to `COPY` into my image resides. For a single version that works pretty well.

However, what if I have multiple versions of my image I need to compile? I might have a stream for 1.2, 1.4 and 2.0, any of which can have patch releases. My Dockerfile itself does installs of various binaries into the image, depending on the version: 1.2 installs mybin 1.2; 1.4 installs mybin 1.4; etc.

So the version of the binary is actually in the Dockerfile.

Then how do I control versions while not having a proliferation of Dockerfiles?

I see a few options:

- Have a single one and edit it, then check it back into git. OK, but then how do I go about building both 1.4.2 and 1.2.7?
- Have multiple directories, e.g. `myimage/1.4/` contains all of the installs for 1.4 (including a Dockerfile, binaries, etc.), while `myimage/2.0/` contains all of the installs for 2.0.
- Have single directory per dot release or even patch release (previous solution taken to the extreme). This feels very redundant.
- Have a single directory for all builds with some automated process to determine my build number, e.g. a script that calls `docker build` and some script gets installed in the image. Seems extremely messy.
- Have a single directory but individual dockerfiles, e.g. `Dockerfile.1.4.2` and `Dockerfile.2.0.7`.

It seems to come down to how much similarity there is between 1.2 and 1.2.7, or 1.2 and 1.4 and 1.0. In other words, do I hardcode the release into the Dockerfile, or try to automate around it?

What is a sane way to manage releases here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is cumbersome, I would go with option #2 (multiple directories) or with an extended version of this using git branches instead of directories.

The guys at docker library (creating/maintaining base image like debian, wordpress, gcc, ...) use the approach with separate directories (see for example [GCC dockerfile on GitHub](https://github.com/docker-library/gcc/tree/master)). This way you can integrate nicely with Docker Hub (e.g. automated builds).
Another option is to use different branches, if you are using git. So you would have your repository `myimage` and then branches for 1.0, 1.2, 1.4 and so on. Now you would also be able to label your patches. Again `Automated builds` from Docker Hub can be used with this approach.

I would say that from a software engineering / release management point of view the branch-based option is the cleanest solution. You can build the different versions of your application from the dedicated branch and then ship it via the proper version of the Dockerfile. This also means you can merge changes from one branch to the other and have it properly documented in the history.

By the way, it seems like best practice to have your Dockerfile in the root folder of your application's source code.

Comment: The git branch solution worked. Since changing to a different version means either my `master` branch has changed and thus the Dockerfile can change, or if I need to maintain multiple versions I maintain multiple git branches which, therefore, can have multiple Dockerfile versions, it is really a clean solution. So thank you.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any idea how to interpolate the version into the Dockerfile? It doesn't seem to like env vars from the outside.

Comment: To clarify: my Dockerfile setup installs files of specific versions. I had hoped to pass the versions via env var. But it looks like Dockerfil only interpolates some env vars (like $PATH)

Comment: @deitch It's not exactly clear to me what you like to achieve. Are you talking about passing your specific versions to `docker build` or to `docker run`? What you usually do in the Dockerfile is to define a variable via `ENV`, which holds the version number (example: [my wine image](https://hub.docker.com/r/suchja/wine/~/dockerfile/)). However, you cannot change this from command line via `docker build`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. I think our build process is a little broken. See, we are slowly converting from an rpm build process via jenkins to an image build process via jenkins. So the logical intermediate step is to keep building rpms, but then install the rpms in the image. Eventually, we eliminate the middle step. Problem? I need to tell it exactly which versions of rpms to install, which means I need to pass params to the Dockerfile.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, your `wine` example. I don't want to have to manually define that `ENV` with each build change.